# Installer (wix built msi) does not remove a feature element (a directory) during uninstallation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, failed-installation

I am having issues getting my installer (msi) to remove a feature based component during uninstallation. The feature element, as per below, contains conditional component group references, which are to a directory id and a number of other components in another fragment (e.g., iis:WebAppPool):

Product.wxs

```
    <Feature Id="StandardIntegration" Level="1" Title="StandardIntegration">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SERVICES"/>
  <!-- Integration Services IIS -->
  <ComponentRef Id="comp1"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="comp2"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="comp3"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="comp4"/>

  <Condition Level="0">
  <![CDATA[HAS_FEATURE_SET <> "true"]]>
</Condition>
</Feature>
```

OtherFragment.wxs

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
  <Directory Id="InstancePath">
    <Directory Id="SERVICES" Name="Services"/>
  </Directory>
</DirectoryRef>

<Component Id="comp1" Directory="SERVICES" Win64="yes" KeyPath="yes" Guid="$(var.c)" MultiInstance="yes" Shared="no">
  <iis:WebAppPool Id="wbpoolid" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" Name="CMP_[NAME]" User="AppPoolUser" Identity="other" RecycleMinutes="0" RecycleRequests="0" ManagedPipelineMode="integrated">
  </iis:WebAppPool>
```

....

All other components referred (including the ones that contains the iis web app pool element) are removed correctly during uninstallation, but the directory ("SERVICES") is not... and it's the only file directory that's not being removed. (E.g., all other files installed by the msi are being correctly removed.)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is there an entry in the PendingFileRenames registry value? It may be something that gets removed on reboot

Comment: Is that the key under 
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager? I don't see anything related on there... what could cause files to be registered there?

Comment: Have you tried using a "RemoveFolder" element?

Comment: If some file was in use or locked Windows installer may mark the file as remove on reboot. I believe the path you posted is correct. It will be a multi_sz registry value that may contain the offending folder/file.

Comment: Are you certain `$(var.c)` is evaluating to something?  If it's blank or null, you won't be able to uninstall the component.

Comment: @philselmer - yes, it definitely evaluates to something. The application pool does remove itself successfully anyways, it's just the services directory that is not being removed.

Comment: @CalumMacLeod - is it okay to use that even if I have not explicitly created the folder via the CreateFolder element? It feels like the msi should remove the directory upon uninstallation in the first place though... since it's doing so for all other directories.

Comment: The other possibility is that there are files beneath SERVICES that were not created by the installer, and therefore are not removed by it.  In that case, it will not attempt to remove the folder and you would want to use `RemoveFolder`.

Comment: @four_seasons It will be safe to do so as long as you can guarantee that there are no files or subfolders within the folder you wish to remove which were not created by your program. I.e. don't call RemoveFolder on any shared directories.

Comment: An uninstall will remove everything. It will not leave a feature or component behind. The likely explanation is that it is shared somehow through your multi-instance use, or that there are files there created by the code. Take a verbose log and see what is says about the component guid. BTW it can also be tricky having empty components with no actual resources - I'd be inclined to add a file or registry entry as the keypath, not the directory.

Comment: @PhilDW Thanks for the advice - I'll try looking for the component guid in the verbose log and also see if I can alter the keypath.